# How to Copy data from XML Column and Insert it into a Table which Contains column names same as XML Tag Names in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database

Say If I have Table which contains Single Column of XML datype
Eg:

```
    Details(Column Name in Table)
    <emp>--row1 in that column
      <Name>Alice</name>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </emp>
    <emp>--row2 in that column
      <Name>Bob</name>
      <ID>2</ID>
    </emp>
```

Now I need to read this column from the table and insert it on to another table which contains same column names as the XML Tag names i.e

```
    Emp
    Name            ID
    Alice           1
    Bob             2
```

I have tried OPENXML ,XQUERY etc . Nothing Seems to work to read column by column and insert into that row . Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CROSS APPLY` on the xml field with the original table should give you the output you need to insert into the target table.

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE (XmlData XML)
DECLARE @Emp TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(15))
INSERT @Source VALUES
    ('<emp><Name>Alice</Name><ID>1</ID></emp><emp><Name>Bob</Name><ID>2</ID></emp>'),
    ('<emp><Name>Max</Name><ID>3</ID></emp>')

INSERT @Emp (ID, Name)
    SELECT
        Employees.Emp.value('ID[1]', 'INT') AS ID,
        Employees.Emp.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS Name
    FROM @Source SRC
        CROSS APPLY SRC.XmlData.nodes('/emp') AS Employees(Emp)

SELECT * FROM @Emp
```

The output from the target table in the example above is below. I added a second record to show how 3 xml "emp" elements across only 2 SQL rows correctly insert 3 target records.

```
ID          Name
----------- ---------------
1           Alice
2           Bob
3           Max
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

```
declare @str_xml xml --- xml data from your column table 

SELECT
    [Table].[Column].value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ' Name ',
    [Table].[Column].value('ID[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' ID '
FROM @str_xml.nodes('/ emp') as [Table]([Column])

Note :
name[1] = name on this must be same with tag <name> not <Name>
```

when you can make output table from xml string you can use it to insert into another table.

http://programcall.com/11/dotnet/how-to-read-data-from-xml-string--and-insert-to-table-sql-server.aspx